# I am trying to send the multiple charts from my Google Sheet with the help of app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting an error while running the app script for sending multiple charts in mail body in html image. However while doing so I am getting an error below is the error.

```
Error   Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1Rs1y1o6bb_XA_XumCrRMYPjS4drHqFvmOIKFyAJXLqA.
    at sendCharts(Code:15:35)
```

Code:

```
    function sendCharts() {

      var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var chartSheet = spSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var bodyEmail = "Hi All, <br> Please find below the Dropship Performance. <br> "
  
      var charts = chartSheet.getCharts();
      var emailCharts = {};
      var bodyChart = "";

      var temp = charts.length

        for(var chartNo=0; chartNo <= temp-1; chartNo++){

            var img = charts[chartNo].getAs("image/png");
            emailCharts["chart" + (chartNo+1)]=img

            bodyChart = bodyChart + "<br><p align='center'><img src='cid:chart" + (chartNo+1)+"'></p>"; 
        }

        bodyEmail = bodyEmail + bodyChart;
        GmailApp.sendEmail("abc@gmail.com", "Latest Report","",{htmlBody:bodyEmail,inlineImages:emailCharts})
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendCharts() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let msgText = "Hi All, <br> Please find below the Dropship Performance. <br> "
  let chts = sh.getCharts();
  let chtObj = {};
  let msgChts = "";
  chts.forEach((cht, i) => {
    chtObj[`chart${i}`] = cht.getBlob();
    msgChts += `<br><img src="cid:chart${i}"/>`;//might wish to add more here
  });
  let html = msgText + msgChts;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv, "Latest Report", "", { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: chtObj })
}
```

This is a crude example with nonsense data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cooper but getting the same error again. I don't get it what is the issue.

Comment: @ShubhGurung Where is the error occurring and what it the complete error message?

Comment: `Error 
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1FDqF63bxl_qHBbE7CgvT6VxTMlRpl4ay9O6y3f5bRlA.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:9
sendCharts @ Code.gs:8`

Comment: I might try making a copy of your spreadsheet and moving all of your scripts to the new spreadsheet.  My best guess is that the spreadsheet has been corrupted somehow.

Comment: sure, tell me your email address, I'll share the spreadsheet with you.

Comment: I even tried a new spreadsheet with my another google account. Shows the same thing I am tired now Please help